# Creating a folder structure from a CSV with duplicates of a single file with a new name

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

But of an odd one this, but hopefully I can make it make sense.

I have a single .aspx file. I want to reuse this file inside a directory structure.
The structure is laid out in a spreadsheet.

So I want to run a script which will take the home.aspx file, duplicate it, and place it in a specific folder (creating the folder if it doesn't exist).

So:

home.aspx will become

```
Training/Policy_and_Admin/Admin/Admin.aspx
Training/Policy_and_Admin/Finances/Finances.aspx
Training/Retirement/Retirement.aspx
Root/SysAdmin/Owner.aspx
```

All the exact same file, just duplicated and placed in the right structure.

Hoping to use powershell to do this, but my experience is limited, happy to use Excel/VBA.

All help appreciated.

Comment: The title mentions a CSV file - what does that look like? Does it store the paths? Does it have column headers?

Comment: Sorry, I did mention CSV, but it is essentially one column with one string. So like D:/Training/Policy_and_Admin/Admin/Admin.aspx
Many rows of that. Storage drive doesn't matter, but I am using D in my testing.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$csvFile = 'c:\temp\test.csv'
$aspx = 'c:\temp\home.aspx'
$destFolders = Get-Content -Path $csvFile
foreach($destFolder in $destFolders)
{
   if (Test-Path -Path $destFolder)
   {
      Copy-Item $aspx -Destination $destFolder
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But that doesn't seem to create the folders, so it errors as the directories aren't there.

Comment: Use Test-Path do check if folder exists.  You may need to create the folder.